# Como valido que cuando un excel no contenga nada no me lo descargue por javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Como puedo validar desde mi siguiente código `js` que cuando la respuesta sea `null` no descargue el fichero `excel` y poder mostrar un mensaje. Ya genero el `excel` con los datos pero en el caso de que no contenga nada la consulta me descarga el `excel` vació y quiero validar eso.

Mi JS

```
    function ExportToExcel() {
        $('#btn-ExportarExcelTab1').on('click', function () {
            var codplaza = $('#Codigo-Plaza').val();
            ajax_download("@Url.Action("CrearExcel", "ImpAuditoriaCinta")", {'cod': cod}, 'ASMCli');
        });
    }

    function ajax_download(url, data, input_name) {
        var $iframe,
            iframe_doc,
            iframe_html;

        if (($iframe = $('#download_iframe')).length === 0) {
            $iframe = $("<iframe id='download_iframe'" +
                        " style='display: none' src='about:blank'></iframe>"
                        ).appendTo("body");
        }

        iframe_doc = $iframe[0].contentWindow || $iframe[0].contentDocument;
        if (iframe_doc.document) {
            iframe_doc = iframe_doc.document;
        }

        iframe_html = "<html><head></head><body><form method='POST' action='" +
                        url + "'>" +
                        "<input type=hidden name='" + input_name + "' value='" +
                        JSON.stringify(data) + "'/></form>" +
                        "</body></html>";

        iframe_doc.open();
        iframe_doc.write(iframe_html);
        $(iframe_doc).find('form').submit();
    }
```

Controlador:

```
    public ActionResult CrearExcel(String cod)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = _IAdi.ExportExcel(cod); // aqui hago la consulta y creo el excel
            if (fileBytes == null) //aqui corto el procedimiento si es nulo si la consulta no contiene nada en IAdi.ExportExcel(cod)
                return null;
            string fileName = "Report.xlsx";
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: No seria mejor que esa validación la hicieras de lado del servidor?

Comment: hago la validación, pero no se en el javascript cuando la respuesta sea null, cuando retorne null desde el controlador mostrar un mensaje. @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de regresar null en el controlador intenta sergresando un script donde indiques que está vacío

```
byte[] fileBytes = _IAdi.ExportExcel(cod); 
if (fileBytes == null) 
     return Content("<script>alert("Excel nulo !");</script>");;
```

Comment: No es el codplaza es la data que me devuelve.

Comment: Ok creo que ya entendí la pregunta y reedite la respuesta, espero sirva de algo